# Can I make two subclasses with methods returning each others' types?

Tags: typescript, types

I have two classes with methods that return each other:

```js
class City {
  
  (...)

  mayor(): Person {
    return this.people[0];
  }
}

class Person {
  
  (...)

  birthCity(): City {
    return this.cities.birth;
  }
}
```

I want to have a mutable and immutable version of each class. The return values would be updated so mutables return mutables and immutables return immutables, e.g.:

```js
class MutableCity {
  
  (...)

  mayor(): MutablePerson {
    return this.people[0];
  }

  // new methods here for mutating things
}

class ImmutableCity {
  
  (...)

  mayor(): ImmutablePerson {
    return this.people[0];
  }
}
```

And similarly for `Person`.

My plan was to write a generic abstract class for both `City` and `Person`, and have the mutable and immutable classes inherit from them, allowing them to specify which type they'll return using a type arg:

```js
class AbstractCity<PersonType extends AbstractPerson> {
  
    readonly people: PersonType[];

    constructor(startingPeople: PersonType[]) {
        this.people = startingPeople;
    }

    mayor(): PersonType {
        return this.people[0];
    }
}

class ImmutableCity extends AbstractCity<ImmutablePerson> {}

class MutableCity extends AbstractCity<MutablePerson> {
    electNewbornInfant() { // extension example
        this.people.unshift(
            new MutablePerson(this)
        );
    }
}

class AbstractPerson<CityType extends AbstractCity> {
  
    readonly cities: {
        birth: CityType,
        favorite?: CityType,
    };

    constructor(birthCity: CityType) {
        this.cities = {
            birth: birthCity
        };
    }

    birthCity(): CityType {
        return this.cities.birth;
    }
}

class ImmutablePerson extends AbstractPerson<ImmutableCity> {}

class MutablePerson extends AbstractPerson<MutableCity> {
    chooseFavorite(favoriteCity: MutableCity) {
        this.cities.favorite = favoriteCity;
    }
}
```

But the abstract classes both need each other as type args:

```js
Generic type 'AbstractCity<PersonType>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
Generic type 'AbstractPerson<CityType>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
```

And I can't nest type args infinitely:

```js
class AbstractCity<
  PersonType extends AbstractPerson<
    CityType extends AbstractCity<
      PersonType extends AbstractPerson<
        CityType extends AbstractCity<
          (etc.)
        >
      >
    >
  >
>
```

How can I get these types to rely on each other? Or how else can I solve the problem?

Solutions I've considered but don't work/I don't like:

1. Instead of `AbstractCity<PersonType extends AbstractPerson>` I could just do `AbstractCity<PersonType>`. But then the type system doesn't know what methods I can call on `PersonType`.
2. I could just rewrite the methods in each mutable/immutable class with different return types, but I don't want the read-only methods duplicated.

Note: the classes also have methods that return their own type, and I'm able to get that to work using the polymorphic `this` instead of generics.

Comment: Your first example shouldn't even work because you return `this.city`, which is the method `city` that was called?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE?  Or a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) that demonstrates it?  Otherwise I need to work on setting stuff up with `people` and `city` etc just to get to the starting line.

Comment: The `(...)` is supposed to represent uninteresting code, but I'll make an example that includes that stuff for clarity.

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/572pyd?file=/index.ts)'s a complete version. The error on `new MutablePerson(this)` is just because of imports/ordering, the other two are the problem I'm having.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wORgpW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.  (And ideally the [mre] should be included as plaintext in the question itself and not just available via external link; could you [edit] to include that?) (Also, if you reply, please mention me with @jcalz or I won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz It does, thanks! I guess I just needed to go a level deeper so it could bootstrap the type from itself, so to speak. I had read the MRE page and thought my question included one because I considered setting the property values and so on to be too extraneous to the question, but I've taken your lead on this one and updated the question with the full example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript allows you to write [recursively bounded generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) such as

```
class Foo<F extends Foo<F>> { f?: F }
```

or mutually-recursive generics like either

```
class Foo<F extends Foo<F, B>, B extends Bar<F, B>> { f?: F; b?: B }
class Bar<F extends Foo<F, B>, B extends Bar<F, B>> { f?: F; b?: B }
```

or

```
class Foo<B extends Bar<Foo<B>>> { f?: Foo<B>; b?: B; }
class Bar<F extends Foo<Bar<F>>> { f?: F; b?: Bar<F>; }
```

depending on how much granularity you need in the typings.  These types can sometimes be tricky to deal with, but you should at least be able to define them.  In your example you could either write it like this:

```
class AbstractCity<P extends AbstractPerson<AbstractCity<P>>> {
  readonly people: P[];

  constructor(startingPeople: P[]) {
    this.people = startingPeople;
  }

  mayor(): P {
    return this.people[0];
  }
}

class ImmutableCity extends AbstractCity<ImmutablePerson> { }
class MutableCity extends AbstractCity<MutablePerson> {
  electNewbornInfant() {
    this.people.unshift(new MutablePerson(this));
  }
}

class AbstractPerson<C extends AbstractCity<AbstractPerson<C>>> {
  readonly cities: {
    birth: C;
    favorite?: C;
  };

  constructor(birthCity: C) {
    this.cities = {
      birth: birthCity
    };
  }

  birthCity(): C {
    return this.cities.birth;
  }
}

class ImmutablePerson extends AbstractPerson<ImmutableCity> { }
class MutablePerson extends AbstractPerson<MutableCity> {
  chooseFavorite(favoriteCity: MutableCity) {
    this.cities.favorite = favoriteCity;
  }
}
```

Or possibly like this:

```
class AbstractCity<C extends AbstractCity<C, P>, P extends AbstractPerson<C, P>> {
  readonly people: P[];

  constructor(startingPeople: P[]) {
    this.people = startingPeople;
  }

  mayor(): P {
    return this.people[0];
  }
}

class ImmutableCity extends AbstractCity<ImmutableCity, ImmutablePerson> { }
class MutableCity extends AbstractCity<MutableCity, MutablePerson> {
  electNewbornInfant() {
    this.people.unshift(new MutablePerson(this));
  }
}

class AbstractPerson<C extends AbstractCity<C, P>, P extends AbstractPerson<C, P>> {
  readonly cities: {
    birth: C;
    favorite?: C;
  };

  constructor(birthCity: C) {
    this.cities = {
      birth: birthCity
    };
  }

  birthCity(): C {
    return this.cities.birth;
  }
}

class ImmutablePerson extends AbstractPerson<ImmutableCity, ImmutablePerson> { }
class MutablePerson extends AbstractPerson<MutableCity, MutablePerson> {
  chooseFavorite(favoriteCity: MutableCity) {
    this.cities.favorite = favoriteCity;
  }
}
```

which both compile as-is, although again, you might run into other bootstapping issues...  especially for anything you actually want to be *immutable*, but I'll consider that out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARCYD2SDeAoJSoksCyAQiFAJbw74FLwA2lUSAYhhgDztIQAPAC4RgAEzace7AHwycSAGYB+AFwckAXwDc9TfSLQ4iJAFkArkPMgmAFQDuWPA0Ysokrr37DREjp-YAGiQyGWCybxFxNgoAJ15wuQUVdXZtJAAjNRCtegJmVhCQeL5BKL8pBJCwnLLfGOKq0PlsJWy0zOyI-QIewnAjUjNLayYAeWBkZwYC938eCLroopLPZpa21LWZdKz1MnS+-LcGksj6+e443jkNlI5drsbZQ71cfVxDEhMAQXgrGx0AhfYzICwA8aTOh5VyFH4ZKBCWIIIQAYSoQgAntwAArnZbwxHI-44iCxKAYYDcQlIlHorG425AlxIWIQEBiSlMTFIGAQDAwJgQdQ4gDaAF1dDD8pSieZ-hhYgAKRHFIRUYAAc1JAqFIolAEpmSykEIABZUKAAOj5uuQAF4kKrYuqtTrBRBdCaPiawCBMYqlQaRcaWWyrLFgKaLdbbR7RQAGSXS3IuH0zE5IACSYDAlhAGSF9J5Sz8NOJaIx2JzeaEBaFpPJlI2R1hc3B9YgxfxZYRtP+xe4HcLEEbFOALRTECF-wAchB7BlFcAs8BFCBgEIg6GXObLTb+R6reZgFALYot5N7MM6yOx5SlXuoAaDV6Wa308c4X2K-eqaiezYcs6SrakfxRP9uFRJlphcNkOS5Hl4AxKhoHUWCWQyKgXTNdRUTfE11wAN0VDEIGyfCUx0XAU3gWUkXlIRAywnDizwo0MN3GMrWQ9VoCQR1OMw7DzXUFjzWLFNegIhhPwYcSzWLIM8J3Bhw3MSNo33XjUOtBSZN6GE5NmNga3zO8yXHQCkGAklLMpbgzNvIsqxbGETJvTs-2s2yhEg4cXKxScTXgM0uCgCB2BAEjYjIpViNIkQ2M8kdiw4qStOtHToCtBLYpEASlGixKuyrAzU1kmjDIMAZvjBEYbAcJwqozb8iRAhkANLIDwIHUDUWCHEajxbqbN6vz7P-QakiE+DOWAbleUPPUkDFZNaPo2JGMDZ1XW1ZbhVWw1VIIJ8DztQrdo1fa7XKuSCD9ANlWDVaTtZCAIyjM64yFRNk29IyWq-OYnM7btRt8wdQdSqtgmhhtJrclwPIC0qsR88bB1R4tglRv9gpZacIDnBcl0jVd103bchNO7ifogY9T3PS8FxShGm2AR8YxfO7AfczNfMgrqfAJTH+umwaMfauyOag6aCbg9l5sW7KoHQjKFLw8qCDysiKLuqUQs27blQU5LUXSk1ae0lD+MEjKCE1zIRMUqsMuogGUzNqtlKQACafez7Mp4229Jd3m0yBttTNzcz2asiHxsg+G0cxOHY+c0dEYUVsUbjrOOal-sJtl7HYbZgvxwVmYwowCKopiuLdaSqt1DLrFLats7Vdy4r8odIrG5brEI8qt59CAA)