# How can I type this pattern of classes? (Two groups of classes returning types within their own group, with subclasses also returning them)

Tags: typescript, types

I need four TypeScript classes. Let's call them:

- BlueWhale
- BlueOcean
- OrangeWhale
- OrangeOcean

All the classes will have some methods returning whales and others returning oceans, but the color of the return type will always match the color of the instance the method was called on. Except for the color of the return type, the methods are identical between both classes of whale and both classes of ocean, so each method should be implemented in only one place.

All of the classes will be extended, and in the resulting subclasses the methods mentioned above should return instances of the original four classes, not of themselves. (The colors still match.) The solution shouldn't prevent any of the original classes or their subclasses from having their own individual methods.

For clarity, here are the same requirements in a more verbose form:

- BlueWhale

  - some methods return BlueWhale

    - their implemention is shared with OrangeWhale methods that return OrangeWhale
    - in subclasses, they still return BlueWhale
  - some methods return BlueOcean

    - their implemention is shared with OrangeWhale methods that return OrangeOcean
    - in subclasses, they still return BlueOcean
- BlueOcean

  - some methods return BlueOcean

    - their implemention is shared with OrangeOcean methods that return OrangeOcean
    - in subclasses, they still return BlueOcean
  - some methods return BlueWhale

    - their implemention is shared with OrangeOcean methods that return OrangeWhale
    - in subclasses, they still return BlueWhale
- OrangeWhale

  - some methods return OrangeWhale

    - their implemention is shared with BlueWhale methods that return BlueWhale
    - in subclasses, they still return OrangeWhale
  - some methods return OrangeOcean

    - their implemention is shared with BlueWhale methods that return BlueOcean
    - in subclasses, they still return OrangeOcean
- OrangeOcean

  - some methods return OrangeOcean

    - their implemention is shared with BlueOcean methods that return BlueOcean
    - in subclasses, they still return OrangeOcean
  - some methods return OrangeWhale

    - their implemention is shared with BlueOcean methods that return BlueWhale
    - in subclasses, they still return OrangeWhale

How would you recommend I type these classes?

Comment: What part of typing the classes are you stuck on? What problem are you facing when trying to type the classes? Recommendations on how to do something is not really a question suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kelly I currently don't know any way to do this in TypeScript. I tried a solution based on an answer to [a question I asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73654725/can-i-make-two-subclasses-with-methods-returning-each-others-types), but it doesn't work because (1) TypeScript doesn't recognize a class as matching the type it extends (a generic supplied with a type arg) even if it doesn't add anything extra and (2) my polymorphic `this`s caused subclasses to return themselves.

Comment: How can I change the question to make it suitable? Add the failed implementation?

Comment: What kind of solution are you expecting? Any criteria (the ones you have listed are for the class implementations) for us? I'm particularly confused about "their implemention is shared with OrangeWhale methods that return OrangeOcean". What does this mean? An abstract class? Merely copy-pasting the code for OrangeWhale and changing it a little? Inheritance?

Comment: For example, I end up with something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nak99W) using your definitions of the classes. I don't need to add any types as TypeScript already infers the types of the classes for me. It would help if we got some actual class implementations in JavaScript and what the desired types (and behavior) for them are.

Comment: Maybe you want a generic class factory function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx3LbN)?  It's hard to say without a [mre]... maybe your "failed implementation" would help.  If you want the factory function as an answer I could write it up, let me know.  (If you reply and want me to be notified, please mention me via @jcalz)

Comment: @kelly By "their implementation is shared" I mean that there is one piece of code that defines the two methods (one for each class), with the only difference in the resulting classes being their return type. So no copy-pasting code, because I'm trying to stay DRY. Using an abstract class or inheritance would be fine, but I intentionally didn't specify those details because I didn't want to place arbitrary restrictions on answers.

Comment: (I'm trying to think of other ways to present the question.)

Comment: We don't have any expectations of the *types*, only the classes. What are the types of the classes supposed to be and how do they interact with each other? Is it something like jcalz's example where you cannot assign a blue whale to an orange whale?

Comment: @kelly To my understanding, TypeScript class declarations also implicitly declare types, so it seems to me my description of the classes and the return types of their methods does describe types. Maybe it's confusing because I don't specify that there will also be other, non-matching methods on the four classes, so yes, you wouldn't be able to assign them to each other.

Comment: But please don't spend time on an answer, I'm going to resubmit the question in a different form.